# git clone ssh permission denied

Tags: git, ssh

I followed the instruction at https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys
and typing

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

I get the message

```
Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not
# provide shell access.
```

When I try to clone a repository using ssh

```
git clone ssh://github.com/username/repository.git
```

I get

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

If I type

```
ssh-add -l
```

I see 3 keys one attached with my email address (k1) and other 2 inside `~/.ssh/id_rsa (RSA)` (k2 and k3).
the key k3 is the same of k1

if I type

```
ssh -vT git@github.com
```

everything is fine...the only line that makes me thinking is

```
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version libssh-0.6.0
debug1: no match: libssh-0.6.0
```

Comment: This was super helpful as git error was just saying "Permission denied". When I could confirm that ssh settings are working fine, I realized the issue was git was unable to create directory into current folder due to permission issues.

Comment: In my case, I just need to `cd ~/.ssh/`, and `ssh-add <name-of-key>` first, then could clone.

Comment: Some time the issue may be that the directory ownership may also be wrong which prevent from cloning.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`git clone ssh://github.com/username/repository.git` is wrong. You should be doing:

```
git clone ssh://git@github.com/username/repository.git
```

or better yet:

```
git clone git@github.com:username/repository.git
```

Answer (score 24):

This terribly nondescript error means that the server rejected your connection. Github has a very rich documentation this -

https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey

Update -

Check if the keys and token are setup properly as per the instructions provided by GitHub. If I were you, start from scratch again. May be you haven't properly initialized SSH keys with Github -

`cd ~/.ssh && ssh-keygen
cat id_rsa.pub`

and copy the key into the SSH settings of the Github website.

To clone a Git repository over SSH, you specify ssh:// URL like this:

`$ git clone ssh://user@server/project.git`

or you can use the shorter scp-like syntax for SSH protocol:

`$ git clone user@server:project.git`

Just wanted to make sure you're copying a correct SSH clone URL from your Github account -

[image]

Comment: @gabboshow See the update above? Wherever you're stuck, follow the documentation steps again from scratch and see if you're doing it correctly.

Answer (score 8):

--------- SOLUTION FOR WINDOWS USERS ------------------

Was facing the same problem in windows, solved as below:

after successfully setting up private/public key for git you need to naviagte to :

C:\Program Files\Git\etc\ssh

-- open ssh-config file present under it and add below information :

```
Host github.com
User git
IdentityFile << absolute path to your private key for git >>
```

-- restart power shell and try to clone repository again

```
 git clone  <<url copied from git repo>>
```

Answer (score 4):

If it is a public repository the whole keys thing can be avoided by using the git protocol with the fetch url.

```
git clone git://github.com/username/repository.git
```

Comment: so I guess that means it's using http access under the hood?

Comment: This is was deprecated by github, See https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/