# Can connect to Code Commit SSH but permission denied to git clone

Tags: amazon-iam, aws-codecommit

I'm trying to clone a CodeCommit repository for the first time following the AWS documentation for Windows: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/setting-up-ssh-windows.html.

I've created a key pair and my config file looks like:

```
Host git-codecommit.*.amazonaws.com
User <SSH key name from console>
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I'm able to connect to ssh git-codecommit.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com successfully (to the point where I'm told interactive shells are not supported), so I think that suggests the key pairing and configuration is OK.

When I try toclone the repository, copying the URL from the console:

```
git clone ssh://git-codecommit.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/v1/repos/<repo name>
```

I'm told:

> Permission denied (publickey).
> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
> and the repository exists.

The non-root IAM user has the AdministratorAccess managed policy which does include full access to CodeCommit:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried amending the URL to include user as suggested here: [git clone ssh permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766153/git-clone-ssh-permission-denied) which does not work either.

There is a corporate proxy in between client and server, but would if that was interfering I'd have expected the SSH connection to fail as well.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

**Update**
This works absolutely fine from a non-corporate machine which suggests it's either the client or the network and means I'm able to work around the problem. I would still be interested in the difference between establishing an SSH connection and cloning a repository though.

Comment: Did you also upload the public key that you generated to the AWS console under the users security credentials?

Comment: @vmachan yes I did, but thanks for the suggestion