# git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey) in conda environment on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, github, conda, root

I'm new to coding and am using ubuntu 20.04. The instruction asked "clone my repo (originally from hbprosper) and set it up" then asked to execute the very first command executed. I don't know what to do at this point. The instructions are here : https://a-kapoor.github.io/Pythia8_To_hepmc_To_ROOT/

And here are the lines from the terminal:

```
(pythia8withhepmc2) raseeb@raseeb:~/anaconda3/envs/pythia8withhepmc2$ git clone git@github.com:akapoorcern/hepmc2root.git

Cloning into 'hepmc2root'...

git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).

fatal: Could not read from remote repository.


Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: The URL you used to clone the repo only works if you have a Github account, and have configured your SSH client to use the key for that. Try the https URL instead if you just want to clone it (and not, for example, push commits).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git clone ssh permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766153/git-clone-ssh-permission-denied)

Comment: (Not sure if that's the best possible duplicate; there's a cubic parsec of similar questions.)